# Can't remove ttyS0 from /etc/securetty

Tags: rhel, root, tty, serial-port, serial-console

Running RHEL6.6.  Been trying to secure the system, and am having difficulty disabling root logins over the serial connection.

My understanding is that I need to comment-out/remove the ttyS0 line, however the next time I reboot/login, the file has been modified and again contains the line ttyS0.

I should note that I am accessing/configuring the server using this serial port.

```
[steve@localhost ~]$ sudo cat /etc/securetty
console
vc/1
vc/2
vc/3
vc/4
vc/5
vc/6
vc/7
vc/8
vc/9
vc/10
vc/11
tty1
tty2
tty3
tty4
tty5
tty6
tty7
tty8
tty9
tty10
tty11
ttyS0
[steve@localhost ~]$
```

**EDIT**

I located an equivalent question on the [redhat website](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/270633)

Similar to what Stephen Harris answered, the solution is to comment out the line

```
 pre-start exec /sbin/securetty $DEV
```

in `/etc/init/serial/conf`

Comment: Do you have a `console=` setting in `/proc/cmdline`? I'm betting you do, and that some boot process is making sure that the `console=` value is present in `/etc/securetty`. Also depending on the exact setup, removing root from serial logins is likely not benefiting security. Someone with serial access could still reboot the box, and then change bootloader params to get in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RedHat 6 there is an upstart script `/etc/init/serial.conf` that will ensure the console is designated a secure terminal before starting the getty process, and so ensuring root can login on the console.

You may be better off setting the root password to something unknown, thus forcing people to always login as a non-root user and then using `sudo` to switch to root for those authorised to become root.